# Prove that $f(x)>0$ near $x=0$

Tags: functions

Given that $f(x) \in C^{5}$ and $$ f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=f^{(3)}(0)=f^{(4)}(0)=0 $$ $$f^{(5)}(0)>0 $$

Prove that $$f(x)>0$$ near $x>0$

I know that this can be proved with Taylor's expansion, but can it be proved using the definition of the derivative and the Mean value theorem by proving that $f^{(4)}(x)>0$ near $x>0$ and so on with the rest of the derivatives?

Comment: First you need to copy the problem correctly. Your "Prove that in $f(x)>0$ near $x>0$" makes no sense - what the problem asked was "Prove that $f(x)>0$ for $x>0$ near $0$". Yes, this can be done very easily by MVT, exactly as the hint for the problem says. What do you get when you attempt to apply MVT to deduce something about $f^{(4)}(x)$ for $x>0$ near $0$? (Two hints: $f^{(5)}$ is the derivative of $f^{(4)}$, and you're given that $f^{(5)}$ is continuous, which shows that $f^{(5)}>0$ for $x>0$ near $0$.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yup edited. I translated it from my language.. I'm a bit weak with this English mathematics!

Comment: Hmm. I figured English was not your native language, but I assumed you'd been given the problem in English (in which case simply copying it correctly would be good to help with the English). The idea that it was your own English translation hadn't occurred to me - if it had I wouldn't have been so snarky. Sorry. (I leave it as an exercise to figure out what "snarky" means...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I really wonder how you come that using MVT was given as a hint for this problem. I don't like the tone of your comment, even though you apologized.

Comment: @wythagoras Seems pretty clear. Because the solution using MVT is so utterly trivial. I can imagine the OP being given a hint to use MVT and not seeing how it applied. But that would indicate that he hadn't really internalized MVT sufficiently; I can't imagine him understanding MVT well enough to conjecture on his own that it might apply without also seeing _how_ it applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is $C^5$, $f^5$ is continuous and, therefore, $> 0$ on a neighbourhood of $0$.

From there, you can use the mean value theorem, or simply integrate $f^5$ around 0, and repeat.

Comment: Thank you for giving me relief! I have the full solution for this question.. If needed by someone I will post it.
Cheers.

Comment: @SijaanHallak It is a good idea to post your solution, so that others who visit the question can also see the full solution.